# Calculating number of rows for separate objects (shapefiles) at once in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, atlas, distribution

I have around 750 separate shapefiles of species distribution data.

For each species I want to calculate the number of atlas squares it occurs in. Doing this for each object separately seems a tedious job and I think there might be a faster way of doing this.

An example of the distribution map:
[image: Distribution of three species]

So, Herniaria occurs in three atlas squares (or circles in this case). Hydrochaeris in 19 and Holcus in a whole lot. I have around 750 of these maps and I don't want to select each of these separately, and go to the attribute table to calculate the number of rows (which is the number of atlas squares). I have been trying for a while now, but can't find a way to do this for all the maps at once.

In the best scenario, the end product would be a list/CSV/XLS/TXT file with one column for the species and one column for the abundance (i.e. the number of atlas squares).

I hope this is possible.

Comment: You could mash (aka `merge`) all data into one shapefile, then `dissolve` by species, then calculate the area for each species, and since you know the size of a square, you then know how many squares you got.

Comment: Do you use PyQGIS ?

Comment: @VincentBré, I use the regular QGIS 3.6.3 NOOSA, i am not faniliar with Python unfortunately.

Comment: Ok but do you use PyQGIS (Python for QGIS), are you familiar with Python programmation ?

Comment: @Erik, unfortunately this does not work, because it calculates the area of the circle, which is not a perfect square kilometer. I choose to use circles instead of squares for aesthetic reasons, but squares would be better for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a column with aggregate values, for example **count(1, "SPECIES")**, the new column will have the total value for each species.

To make this easier, make all shapefiles with the same columns and merge them.
Create the new quantity column, do the calculation and dissolve the shape by "SPECIES".

The result will be a shape with one line for each species found and the total value next to it. Just save as CSV or XLSX.

If merging the shapes is not an option, create a model to perform these steps and run it in batch.

Comment: This works, thanks a lot!